# HTTP headers list

Tags: django

I am studying Django and have created a page that shows all HTTP headers in a request using request.META dictionary. I'm running it locally and it the page shows me a weird amount of headers like 'TEMP' containing the path to my Windows temp folder, or 'PATH' with my full path parameters and much more information that I don't really find necessary to share in my browser requests (like installed applications).
Is it normal? What do I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let's jump quickly into Django's source code:

**django/core/handlers/wsgi.py**

```
class WSGIRequest(http.HttpRequest):
    def __init__(self, environ):
        ...
        self.META = environ
        self.META['PATH_INFO'] = path_info
        self.META['SCRIPT_NAME'] = script_name
        ...
```

This handler is used by default in `runserver` command and every other wsgi server. The `environ` dictionary comes from the underlying web server. And it is filled with lots of data. You can read more about `environ` dictionary here in the official wsgi docs:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables

Also note that any web server is free to add its own variables to `environ`. I assume that's why you see things like `TEMP`. They are probably used internally by the web server.

If you wish to get headers only then wsgi mandates that headers have to start with `HTTP_` prefix with the exception of `CONTENT_TYPE` and `CONTENT_LENGTH` headers.

So Django's docs are misleading. The `META` field contains more then headers only. It is neither correct nor incorrect, it's just how it is. Special care has to be taken when dealing with `META`. Leaking some of the data might be a serious security issue.

Comment: Thank you, freakish. Then, I presume, only those starting with 'HTTP' get actually sent by the user agent to the server. I've changed my code to sort out all the rest, and now the headers that I get are at last similar to what I am used to see.

Comment: @RayP. Yes, with the exception of `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE` headers (inconsistent, I know). Other things that clients send are `REQUEST_METHOD`, `PATH_INFO`, `QUERY_STRING` and `SERVER_PROTOCOL` (yes, it's misleading, it should be called `REQUEST_PROTOCOL`). Some of them are probably available via different Django mechanisms. I think that's the full list of header info.